# How to make all images in the same row scale accordingly to parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have multiple rows with various images count inside each flex div.

Images should always be in the same row no matter what is the width of parent div. Here I am setting max-width: 350px, images should adjust their width accordingly so they fit (in their ratio). If there are 5 images, then each image should be 20% wide. If there are 10 images, each image should be 10% wide and so on.

I know I can set width on image but I would like to skip manual work for each div as there will be many variations.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 350px;
}

img {
  margin: 1px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
```

Comment: min-width:0 to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the images in a div otherwise flex won't resize them

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.img-holder {
  margin: 1px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
</div>
```